# convert SQL to LINQ query

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda

i want to convert this query into LINQ or with lambda expression

```
    ALTER procedure  [dbo].[grid_data]
   @fromdate datetime,
   @todate  datetime,
   @region   varchar(50)
    as
    Select D.ID as ID, D.OName,  
    (Select Count(*) from tblve WHERE MID = D.ID and Vme <> ''),  
    D.Mil,D.Speed  
    from tblRe M  
    inner join tblReg D  
    On M.RID = D.RID
```

I try this method but this show error on count

```
[WebMethod]
     public static string search_data(DateTime fromdate, DateTime todate, string region)
    { 
        try
        {  
          T1 ts = new T1();
          var query = (from M in ts.tblRe 
          join D in ts.tblReg on M.RID equals D.RID
          where 
          M.Region == region
          && M.StartDate <= fromdate
          && M.EndDate >= todate
          select new {                      
          D.ID,
          D.OName,
          Count = ts.tblve.Where(x => x.MID == D.ID && x.Vme !=  
          '').Count()
          D.Mil,
          D.Speed
         }).ToList();
```

THIS SHOWS ERROR
    Empty character literal 
on this line `'')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this solution:

```
  var query = from M in context.tblRe 
              join D in context.tblReg on M.RID equals D.RID
              where M.StartDate <= fromdate && M.EndDate >= todate && M.region == region 
              select new {                      
                  D.ID,
                  D.OName,
                  Count = context.tblve.Where(x => x.MID == D.ID && x.Vme != "").Count()
                  D.Mil,
                  D.Speed
              };
```

Comment: what about where ? there is also parameters check update please

Comment: how to pass parameters

Comment: First, now it is not simple query, but procedure; second you not use parameters inside your query, third linq-to-sql not supports procedures.

Comment: no i mean forget this line  ALTER procedure  [dbo].[grid_data] except this line other is real query

Comment: Do you want to add some parameters into your query? Specify place, where they should be located.

Comment: replace `''` with `""`

Comment: one thing more please in this line  (Select Count(*) from tblve WHERE MID = D.ID and Vme <> ''),   there is no column name so i set column name in linq